# Add 0xFFFFFFFF in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm currently reversing disassembly and stumbled upon a chain of instructions I don't understand:

Given an object pointer in `esi`.

```
.text:00C20263                 cmp     dword ptr [esi+80h], 0
.text:00C2026A                 jnz     short loc_C2027D
```

As you can see if the member `+0x80` is not 0 (the member is an integer) the code jumps to `00C2027D`:

```
.text:00C2027D                 add     dword ptr [esi+80h], 0FFFFFFFFh
.text:00C20284                 jnz     short loc_C20291
```

These two instructions are those I don't really understand. First of all, the member is incremented by 0xFFFFFFFF; but since the member is not 0, wouldn't this exceeds the max value of an 32-bit integer? And when does the `jnz` instruction jumps?

Could one maybe point out what the purpose of these two instructions is?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a signed variable, 0FFFFFFFFh is the same as -1, so this is subtracting one from the value and checking if that made it zero. Compilers will often emit "add negative value" rather than a sub instruction, presumably because it allows for reuse of compiler logic for both addition and subtraction.

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes completely sense at this point.

Comment: @MihaiLabo Im very sorry about this, as i read this answere i wasnt able to press it and then simply forget about it ;)

Comment: You're just answering only one instruction, not two.
For the `jnz` instruction: jump to `short loc_C20291` if zero flag is 0.